# How to execute a string as query in meteor

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to execute a string as a query in meteor?
If I have a collection named `SampleCollection`

```
const collectionName = 'SampleCollection';
const _query = collectionName+'.find()';
```

How can i execute `_query`?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, try this:

```
const collectionName = 'SampleCollection';
const _query = collectionName+'.find()';
var func = new Function(_query);
func();
```

Comment: Thanks @Kuba. However, the Function constructor is eval here. Thanks anyways.